ST_ClusterKMeans followed by Convex Hull gives overwhelmingly overlapped polygons
Here is my code:
-- By area id

with nta_clusters as 

(
select *,

ST_ClusterKMeans(st_transform("centerPoint",24313), 1 ,5000) OVER (partition by "areaID" order by "ID") AS nta_cluster_id


FROM potential_missed_areas pma 

where pma.campaignid=-1
)

SELECT 
    nta_cluster_id,
    ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect("centerPoint")) AS convex_hull
FROM 
    nta_clusters
GROUP BY 
    nta_cluster_id;

This results in highly overlapped polygons as shown below.

This is a consequence of partitioning. When calling ST_ClusterKMeans without a partition, clusters are numbered 0 to n. When calling with a partition, for each partitioned value, the cluster id will again be numbered from 0 to n.
When calling ST_ConvexHull, you are only aggregating by cluster id, so the points are aggregated between partitions. Try grouping by "areaID", nta_cluster_id
